# Fourier transform visualising

Tags: fourier-transform, visualization

Is there any way to visualize a Fourier transform? I mean, if I am given a function, can I roughly guess what its Fourier transform should look line before doing the mathematics?

Suppose I am given the standard function, $f(x)=1$ for $|x|<1$. Its Fourier transform is of the form $\dfrac{\sin(k)}{k}$.

I want to know: can I guess this nature of the transform roughly using any logical arguments before doing the mathematics? I mean,the positions of zeros of the transform,or it will decay or not at higher value of k,and things like that.

Comment: How is this a question specifically about physics? Might this question be better suited for [math.SE]?

Comment: With some experience. That function is like a slit that gives a diffraction pattern.

Comment: @ACuriousMind this question generated in my mind while performing fourier transform to get the diffraction pattern.This ia why i posted this in physics

Comment: I found this to be an excellent article to help me visualize the fourier transform. https://betterexplained.com/articles/an-interactive-guide-to-the-fourier-transform/